# Return sheet #'s when value matches

Tags: excel, list

I have a workbook built with a large number of sheets, and I'm trying to build an automatic search function that checks them all for a value in the active sheet.  Basically, I want to have a single cell, lets say O2, return the values of A2 on each sheet where the first 15 characters of A1 match A1 on the active sheet.  These values taken from A2 would want to be in list form, separated by comma's.
Any input here would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. Be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your 1st badge!) and see "[ask]", and also the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site.  If you have a *specific* problem with a certain section of your code, you can [edit] your post to share an **[mcve]** as well as sample data and some background info.  Here are some  [tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user. Good Luck!

Comment: Have you tried anything? What kind of solution are you looking for? VBA? Formula? Manual steps?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit of pseudo-code or outline that you might start with.  It takes the form of a VBA subroutine.  Start coding it and when you have problems, google the problem and solve it yourself.  (Or paste your code in and ask for help).

```
dim AnsSheet as string
AnsSheet = "xxx"
For S# = 0 to S#max - 1
    if S#.name = AnsSheet, then bypass
    if S#.Cells(A1).first15char = AnsSheet.Cells(A1).first15char then
        AnsSheet.Cells(O2) = AnsSheet.Cells(O2) & ", " & S#.Cells(A2)
    endif
Next S#
AnsSheet.Cells(O2) strip off leading ", " from the first result
```